# Can anyone help me in fixing this error / warning FutureWarning: 'normalize' was deprecated in version 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4tD2.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ASd7.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaNXs.png)

> FutureWarning: 'normalize' was deprecated in version 1.0 and will be removed in 1.2.
> If you wish to scale the data, use Pipeline with a StandardScaler in a preprocessing stage. To reproduce the previous behavior:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

model = make_pipeline(StandardScaler(with_mean=False), LinearRegression())
```

I tried to suppress the warning but the outcome was wrong.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Do you understand what "deprecated" means? "I tried to suppress the warning but the outcome was wrong." Please read [ask] and [mre].

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to suppress the warning then you can use this :

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```